# How to speed up the addition of a new column in pandas, based on comparisons on an existing one

Tags: performance, python-3.x, pandas

I am working on a large-ish dataframe collection with some machine data in several tables. The goal is to add a column to every table which expresses the row's "class", considering its vicinity to a certain time stamp.

```
    seconds = 1800

    for i in range(len(tables)): # looping over 20 equally structured tables containing machine data

        table = tables[i]
        table['Class'] = 'no event'

        for event in events[i].values: # looping over 20 equally structured tables containing events

            event_time = event[1] # get integer time stamp
            start_time = event_time - seconds
            table.loc[(table.Time<=event_time) & (table.Time>=start_time), 'Class'] = 'event soon'
```

The `event_time`s and the entries in `table.Time` are integers. The point is to assign the class "event soon" to all rows in a specific time frame before an event (the number of seconds).

The code takes quite long to run, and I am not sure what is to blame and what can be fixed. The amount of seconds does not have much impact on the runtime, so the part where the table is actually changed is probabaly working fine and it may have to do with the nested loops instead. However, I don't see how to get rid of them. Hopefully, there is a faster, more *pandas* way to go about adding this class column.

I am working with Python 3.6 and Pandas 0.19.2

Comment: can you post what `event` looks like?

Comment: `events` is a normal Python list containing 20 data frames, each of which has some 30 columns or so with event descriptions. Only column 1 with the integer timestamp is being used of these tables.

Comment: what are the lengths of the `table` and `event` DataFrames

Comment: The lengths vary, as there are 20 each. But in general the `table` (millions of entries) is a lot longer than `events` (some hundreds of entries at maximum).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `numpy` broadcasting to do this vectotised instead of looping

## Dummy data generation

```
num_tables = 5
seconds=1800

def gen_table(count):
    for i in range(count):
        times = [(100 + j)**2 for j in range(i, 50 + i)]
        df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Time': times})
        yield df

def gen_events(count, num_tables):
    for i in range(num_tables):
        times = [1E4 + 100 * (i + j )**2 for j in range(count)]
        yield pd.DataFrame(data={'events': times})

tables = list(gen_table(num_tables))  # a list of 5 DataFrames of length 50
events = list(gen_events(5, num_tables)) # a list of 5 DataFrames of length 5
```

## Comparison

For debugging, I added a dict of verification DataFrames. They are not needed, I just used them for debugging

```
verification = {}
for i, (table, event_df) in enumerate(zip(tables, events)):
    event_list = event_df['events']
    time_diff = event_list.values - table['Time'].values[:,np.newaxis] # This is where the magic happens
    events_close = np.any( (0 < time_diff) & (time_diff < seconds), axis=1)
    table['Class'] = np.where(events_close, 'event soon', 'no event')
    # The stuff after this line can be deleted since it's only used for the verification
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=time_diff, index=table['Time'], columns=event_list)
    df['event'] = np.any((0 < time_diff) & (time_diff < seconds), axis=1)
    verification[i] = df
```

## newaxis

A good explanation on `broadcasting` is in Jakevdp's [book](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/jakevdp/PythonDataScienceHandbook/blob/master/notebooks/02.05-Computation-on-arrays-broadcasting.ipynb)

`table['Time'].values[:,np.newaxis]`

gives a (50,1) 2-d array

```
array([[10000],
       [10201],
       [10404],
       ....
       [21609],
       [21904],
       [22201]], dtype=int64)
```

## Verification

For the first step the verification df looks like this:

```
events     10000.0     10100.0     10400.0     10900.0     11600.0     event
Time                         
10000     0.0          100.0      400.0       900.0       1600.0      True
10201     -201.0      -101.0      199.0       699.0       1399.0      True
10404     -404.0      -304.0      -4.0        496.0       1196.0      True
10609     -609.0      -509.0      -209.0      291.0       991.0       True
10816     -816.0      -716.0      -416.0      84.0        784.0       True
11025     -1025.0     -925.0      -625.0      -125.0      575.0       True
11236     -1236.0     -1136.0     -836.0      -336.0      364.0       True
11449     -1449.0     -1349.0     -1049.0     -549.0      151.0       True
11664     -1664.0     -1564.0     -1264.0     -764.0      -64.0       False
11881     -1881.0     -1781.0     -1481.0     -981.0      -281.0      False
12100     -2100.0     -2000.0     -1700.0     -1200.0     -500.0      False
12321     -2321.0     -2221.0     -1921.0     -1421.0     -721.0      False
12544     -2544.0     -2444.0     -2144.0     -1644.0     -944.0      False
....
20449     -10449.0     -10349.0     -10049.0     -9549.0     -8849.0     False
20736     -10736.0     -10636.0     -10336.0     -9836.0     -9136.0     False
21025     -11025.0     -10925.0     -10625.0     -10125.0     -9425.0     False
21316     -11316.0     -11216.0     -10916.0     -10416.0     -9716.0     False
21609     -11609.0     -11509.0     -11209.0     -10709.0     -10009.0     False
21904     -11904.0     -11804.0     -11504.0     -11004.0     -10304.0     False
22201     -12201.0     -12101.0     -11801.0     -11301.0     -10601.0     False
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that definitely cleared up broadcasting for me, and the result is looking good, too! However, it does not seem to run any faster than the original version - if anything, a little slower. (I got about 53/58/46/47/46 s of runtime for the nested loops and 62/54/55/56/57 s for the vectorized version, though, admittedly, these are only a few individual examples.) Is it possible that the amount of data is the actual problem here?

Comment: Is it also slower when deleting the verification code? And at any rate, comparing 20 time millions of rows with hundreds of values can be slow. You might try [profiling](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html) to see where the bottleneck is

Comment: I left out the verification code (after verifying it worked). Trying the profiling now, let's see what comes up!

Comment: Well, cProfile comes to the conclusion that both versions, called as functions nested or vectorized, take somewhere between 50 and 60 seconds, most of which is being spent in the function itself. The nested version, however, also spends smaller amounts of time with various work, such as `format.py:235(to_string)` or `{method 'copy' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}`, while the vectorized code does not depend on so many calls and mostly uses numpy methods. It seems like for the current amount of data they may be equally suited.

Comment: in what part of the function is most time spent? in the `time_diff` generation, the `events_close = np.any( (0 < time_diff) & (time_diff < seconds), axis=1)` part or the `np.where` call?

Comment: The "any" part has more `cumtime` associated in the cProfile report. After the whole function itself (about 60 seconds), the next largest `cumtime`s are between about 5 and 1 seconds for (from large to small): `frame.py:2405(__setitem__)`, `indexing.py:1769(convert_to_index_sliceable)`, `index.py:1464(_get_string_slice)`, [...] , `frequencies.py:774(get_freq)`, **`_methods.py:37(_any)`**, **`fromnumeric.py:1866(any)`**, **`{method 'any' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}`**, `{method 'reduce' of 'numpy.ufunc' objects}`, [...].

Answer (score 0):

#### Small optimizations of original answer.

You can shave a few lines and some assignments of the original algorithm

```
for table, event_df in zip(tables, events):
    table['Class'] = 'no event'
    for event_time in event_df['events']: # looping over 20 equally structured tables containing events
        start_time = event_time - seconds
        table.loc[table['Time'].between(start_time, event_time), 'Class'] = 'event soon'
```

You might shave some more if instead of the text `'no event'` and `'event soon'` you would just use booleans

Comment: Good point with the booleans, that takes away a few seconds from the runtime on average. Also, the code is much shorter now. Thanks a bunch!